# PayPal html button for digital goods

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm having a problem with a PayPal button that I made. Yesterday I got my first sale of a digital good on my website, everything worked well except at the end when PayPal blocked the payment.

I called them to know why and they explained me that it was because the order was made for physical products and the shipping information was missing.

They unblocked the payment but I can't find how to set that the payment is for digital goods.

My code below:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my email">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IT">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="product">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="00.00">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="mysite">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="mysite">
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_SM.gif:NonHosted">
            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="userid" />
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="IPN ">
            <input type="image" src="img/paypal1.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct to not collect shipping for a digital good, `no_shipping=1`.  Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables

Perhaps you were misinformed as to why the payment was on hold.

One thing you can do is to ensure the item name makes clear that it is something digital.

Comment: It is Elaborated File, more clear than this haha.

Comment: Thank you anyway,

Comment: The paymant was on hold, as the paypal calcenter said, because they said it was a payment for phisical product...
I also saw there is another kind of button makable with javascript but I realy did't understand anything about it!

Comment: The newer button will work the same way if you pass the right variable to avoid collecting a shipping address (`shipping_preference : "NO_SHIPPING"` in the request's `application_context`, ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#orders-create-request-body )